# Is there a method for login with email & password in @auth0/auth0-angular?

Tags: angular, auth0

[Auth0 SDK for Angular Single Page Applications](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular) - in docs there are 2 methods for login:

- loginWithPopup
- loginWithRedirect

Could we provide one more way to login with simple email & password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use in that case the **Resource Owner Password Flow**.

make sure that your **Grant Types** includes **Password**, you will then call the oauth token api with your credentials and get an **access token**

[image]

check this https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-resource-owner-password-flow